# why do we give ICW 1 to port 0x20 but other ICWS to port 0x21 when initializing a PIC(8259)?

Tags: x86, kernel, pic, osdev

I am writing a keyboard device driver.While configuring PIC ICW1 is give to port 0x20 and other ICWS to port 0x21 but I don't understand why we have two ports and how they are connected to pins on 8259 chip?

I already read the manual but still cannot understand how it is exactly connected to the ports on the x86 processor.

```
outb(0x20, 0x11);       /* send ICW1 */
outb(0xA0, 0x11);

/* send ICW2 */
outb(0x20 + 1, pic1);   /* remap */
outb(0xA0 + 1, pic2);   /*  pics */

/* send ICW3 */
outb(0x20 + 1, 4);  /* IRQ2 -> connection to slave */
outb(0xA0 + 1, 2);

/* send ICW4 */
outb(0x20 + 1, 0x01);
outb(0xA0 + 1, 0x01);
```

Comment: There are 2 IO ports reserved in the IO address space of the PC for each of the legacy PICs (8259As). One is the comand port and the other is the data port. The A0 line of the 8259A is tied to the address bus of the PC which switches between the ports being addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port number used with `in` and `out` are placed in the address bus, the lines that make this bus are connected to the device.
Devices are not connected to ports, instead ports are numbers sent to all devices.
In a well configured system only a single devices reacts for a given number (port) placed on the address bus.
Of course, this is a simplified view of the bus model, it's how the PC/XT and ISA bus worked from a functional point of view.

---

The 8259A has a CS pin that must be low to activate the chip. With a bit of logic gates this pin can be made asserted only when the address bus has a range of value.
For example, assuming for the sake of shortness that the address bus is 8-bit wide, if the address lines A7 - A4 are ANDed together to form CS, then the 8259A will respond to the range 0xf0 - 0xff.
Simply put, excluding some address lines from the input of the function that computes CS create a range of addresses to which the 8259A responds.
Particularly, excluding the lines from A0 up to An makes a continuous range of size 2<sup>n</sup> which starting address has the lowers *n* bit cleared.

The 8259A has only two registers, so we need a range of size 2, or equivalently an *n* equals to 1.
So, A7 - A1 are used to compute CS. Note that some architecture may have *aliasing*, IIRC this was also present during the extension of the ISA bus.
Aliasing occurs if an address line can be driven by the CPU but it is not connected to neither to the block that computes CS nor to the device.

The address lines not used for CS must be used to select a register internal to the device (if not all of them are used, aliasing occurs).
Since the 8259A has only two registers, we'd expect a single pin to select between these two registers.
In fact, that's what the A0 pin does:

> **A0 ADDRESS LINE**: This pin acts in conjunction with the CS, WR, and
>   RD pins. It is used by the 8259A to decipher various Command Words
>   the CPU writes and status the CPU wishes to read. It is typically
>   connected to the CPU A0 address line (A1 for 8086, 8088).

By making the A7-A1 lines drive CS high only when their value is (in binary) 0010_000 and by connecting the CPU A0 line to the A0 pin we make the 8259A responds to the addresses 0x20 and 0x21.

```
            ____
----A7----O|    \             _________
----A7----O|     \           |         | 
----A6----O|      )-----CS---|         |
   ...     |     /           |         |
----A1----O|____/            |  8259A  |
                             |         |
----D7------------------D7---|         |
    ...                      |         |
----D0------------------D0---|         |
                             |         |
----A0------------------A0---|_________|
```

---

## Why the ICW1 goes to 0x20 and the other ICWs to 0x21

Well, the correct answer is: because so does say the datasheet.
My interpretation is that the 0x21 port is used to read/write the mask register, since all the 8 bits are used for the 8 IRQ lines of the 8259A, all the 256 possible values writable to that port already mean something.
The logic behind the port 0x21 cannot tell if the byte written is an ICW or an OCW, so port 0x21 cannot be used to send ICW1.

To trigger ICW1, bit 4 must be 1. This means each time bit 4 is 1 when writing to port 0x20, the 8259A detects ICW1 and enters the initialization sequence.
Since ICW2 and ICW3 (for masters) need *all* of the 8 bits, including bit 4, they cannot be send to port 0x20.
So ICW2 and ICW3 must go to port 0x21.
Finally, ICW4 also used D4 but could be re-engineered to not use it but since the previous two ICWs were using port 0x21, it was used for ICW4 too.

Could it be made different? Yes, of course. Maybe with a command register and a data register (along with the mask register access) but evidently at the time this solution was easier to implement.
It has less port to decode, and possibly a shorter DFA to handle to device state (I haven't checked, though).

---

I don't know why for 8086/8 system it was the address line A1 that was connected to the pin A0.